# Integration to find displacement field - Axisymmetric disk

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Dear mathematical acolytes,

I am having trouble understanding a step in the solution of a differential equation related to solid mechanics. The problem is an axisymmetric disk that is subjected to a temperature field which gives rise to a displacement field through the equation of equilibrium. The solution I am referring to can be found in Chapter 6 of the book Thermal Stresses -- Advanced Theory and Applications which in turn can be found at https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4020-9247-3. The differential equation is as follows:

$ \frac{d}{dr} \left[ \frac{1}{r} \frac{d\left( ur \right)}{dr} \right] = \frac{1 + \nu}{1 - \nu} \alpha \frac{d\theta}{dr} $

where $ u $ is the displacement field, $ r $ is the radial coordinate, $ \theta $ is the temperature field (comes from another solution), and $ \nu $ and $ \alpha $ are material parameters. The solution is found by integration in the book, but no steps of how this is done are shown. The solution given in the book is

$ u = \frac{1 + \nu}{1 - \nu} \frac{\alpha}{r} \int_0^r{\theta r dr} + C_1r + \frac{C_2}{r} $

I understand the last two terms $ C_1r + \frac{C_2}{r} $ of the solution, which can be found by solving $ \frac{d}{dr} \left[ \frac{1}{r} \frac{d\left( ur \right)}{dr} \right] = 0 $. But I do not understand the steps necessary to reproduce the first term of the solution with the integral over the temperature field.

**Is there anyone who can help me understand this problem?**

*Some additional info:*
The reason I want to understand this is to be able to solve a slightly more complicated expression, which is

$ \frac{d}{dr} \left[ \frac{1}{r} \frac{d\left( ur \right)}{dr} \right] = -\frac{1 - 2\nu}{1 - \nu} \left(\frac{2\varepsilon_p}{r} + \frac{d\varepsilon_p}{dr}\right) $

Where the term containing the temperature field is replaced by a term containing plastic strains $ \varepsilon_p $.

**If guidance could be given also to this, it would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Integrate left and right hand sides with respect to $r$.  Then multiply through by $r$ and integrate again.